# How to return results using a list of maps in mybatis

Tags: java, sql, persistence, mybatis

My mapper interface is like

```
public interface InstructorMapper {
    final String getEmailUsers = "SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS users FROM instructor GROUP BY email";
@Select(getEmailUsers)
    List<Map<String,Integer>> getEmailUsers();
}
```

The main code is as follows.

```
List<Map<String,Integer>> users = instructorMapper.getEmailUsers();
            System.out.println(users); //prints everything as null
            System.out.println(users.size());  //prints 200, Beacause there are 200 records in the instructor table
```

I have also tried to iterate over individual map entries in the list and tried to print their keySet() and values() but everything print null only. So what is happening here.Any MyBatis expert here?

Answer (score 0):

Try?

```
List<Map<String,Integer>> users = instructorMapper.getEmailUsers();
for (Map<String, Integer> user : users) {
    System.out.println(user);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have but it is printing everything as null only